# In WebStorm, can I disable completion of JavaScript keywords in HTML in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, webstorm, jsx

WebStorm seems to auto-complete JavaScript keywords while typing normal text in JSX. I have to keep pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or click elsewhere to hide the auto-complete popup, which is becoming very annoying. Is it possible to disable this? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the Settings and have already searched online.

This screenshot illustrates the problem. If I don't press <kbd>ESC</kbd> or click elsewhere to remove the popup, the `a` will be replaced with `async`.

[image: Screenshot illustrating the problem described]

**Edit:**
I don't want to disable auto-completion altogether, though it does serve as a workaround. What I really want is to disable auto-completion in JSX only.

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31285

Answer (score 2):

In WebStorm go to File | Settings | Editor | General | Code completion. Just turn off "Auto insert" check and "Autopopup code completion" check.

Comment: Indeed, this can only be turned off completely, not selectively for each language.

Comment: I'm guessing I have a different version of WebStorm because I have different options. But nevertheless this turns it off for all languages, not just HTML or JSX.

Comment: Mine is 2017.3.1

Comment: @LazarNikolic ah mine is 2018.2.2.